lineend with transparency produces artifacts in geom_line
I am wanting to plot a semi-transparent line with rounded ends, but it seems that geom_line may plot in segments resulting in several line "ends" in the middle of the line.
Here is simple code that reproduces this artifact:
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)

tmp <- tibble(x=seq(350), y=seq(350))
tmp %>% ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_line(alpha=0.3, linewidth=6, lineend="round")



If I use lineend="square" I get squares rather than circles and only "butt" produces a clean line. Using more points produces more overlaps/segments.
Any suggestions or workarounds?  Thanks!

I can't reproduce this in the latest version of ggplot2 using ragg as a plotting device. Are you able to tell us your ggplot version and plotting device?

I can reproduce OP's output in my RStudio viewer pane, but the problem is alleviated when saving to ragg png. So I suggest switching to ragg.

Could not reproduce in RStudio viewer pane (RStudioGD), R 4.4.1, ggplot2 3.5.1, Win10.

This was using R 4.4.1 and ggplot2 3.5.1 and the image was from the quartz viewer.  Using ragg for output does solve the problem.  Thanks!
